# Not able to open PuTTy key generator on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I am really new to PuTTY and PuTTY key generator as I am trying to setup EC2 on AWS. I have managed to install PuTTY on my Mac, and PuTTY works fine, but every time I click on PuTTY key generator I see a message (please see the snap attached) and no pop up window. how do I get it to work? I have Mac Mojave.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the output you shared because when you run `puttygen`, it's expecting mandatory command-line arguments to be passed.

- I'm unsure why you're trying to use `puttygen` since it's mainly used on Windows to generate an SSH key pair. You don't generally need to use it on Mac since Mac OS has a built-in command-line SSH client known as Terminal.

To use Terminal, from the top menu, go to Finder > click Menus > Go > Utilities. 
 Find the terminal which supports SSH connections to remote servers.

**Generate KeyPair**

- Use `ssh-keygen` to generate an SSH KeyPair ([How to Use ssh-keygen](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/create-with-openssh/))

If you simply want to log in to your ec2 instance via SSH, using the keypair from ec2:

```bash
chmod 400 ~/Downloads/myPrivatekeyFile.pem
ssh -i ~/Downloads/myPrivatekeyFile.pem ec2-user@[ip-address]
```

Comment: Hello again, you can open the terminal application and run the ssh command I gave you

Comment: You don't need to convert the .pem to ppk

Comment: you can also see the command to ssh, if you goto ec2 console, click the instance, and click connect button. it will show you the ssh command.

Comment: hi again @Arun K, that was most helpful.  again as you can see am totally new to this as I come from a finance background. I am now able to connect to the ubuntu server. to run a python file say "abc.py" from that sever how do I proceed from here. I have been following the video link I sent previously (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE303yFWfV4&t=247s), would that be applicable to Mac as well or any other way you would recommend. thanks again.

Comment: No those commands you need to execute in the ec2 server via ssh. You can follow that tutorial and post a question in stackoverflow if you have issues with python code.

Comment: glad to be of help.

Comment: hi @Arun K had another question which is more server related. I am using EC2 to run some simulation and as I increased number of simulations to run the server has stopped responding. how do I stop that script now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102704/discussion-between-arun-k-and-praskam).

Answer (score 1):

Linux/Mac version of PuTTYgen is a command-line tool: See [`puttygen` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/putty-tools/puttygen.1.en.html).

It's not a GUI application like the Windows version of PuTTYgen.